# How to setup nginx as reverse proxy to openvpn client ? (nginx 499 timeout error)

Tags: openvpn, nginx, http-proxy

My network architecture is:

```
       srv_pub (reverse nginx proxy)                    srv_target 
           +-----------------+                  +---------------------+
  Internet |      VPS        |  VPN 10.8.0.0/24 |     HOME SERVER     |
-----------> eth0: public_ip <------------------> eth0: non_public_ip |
           | tun0:  10.8.0.1 |                  | tun0: 10.8.0.2      |
           +-----------------+                  +---------------------+
Domains:     pub.example.com  (A DNS record of pub.example.com points to public_ip)
```

On `srv_target` I have docker container with needed app, that must be available on `pub.example.com`

`curl http://pub.example.com` from `srv target` shell is ok.

`curl http://pub.example.com` from `srv pub` shell is ok (added `10.8.0.2 pub.example.com` to `/etc/hosts` and then checked)

`curl http://pub.example.com` from any other IP at Internet is NOT OK, I got `Operation timed out`. And it's not a problem of my provider, I also check domain availability using [reqbin](https://reqbin.com/curl) and [google](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results/result), same result.

My nginx conf for `pub.example.com` host on `srv_pub` looks like:

```
upstream app {
    server 10.0.8.2;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name pub.example.com;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://app;
        }
}
```

tailing nginx `access.log` on `srv_pub` shows `"GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "curl/7.68.0"`

`ufw` on `srv_pub` is disabled.

`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` shows `1`

What else could be wrong? And how can I debug it?

Comment: This is correct configuration. You don't need IP forwarding (at least, for this part). Probably, the `srv.example.com` is answering with 499 code? Check its logs. If it was inaccessible from VPS, Nginx would reply 5xx code, not 4xx.

Comment: Apparently, 499 is nginx logging the client closed the connection prematurely. It is not the actual error. // As commented on the deleted question, I strongly urge you use `tcpdump` to check on both hosts and all interfaces where traffic arrives and leaves when whether it is the traffic you expect.

Comment: @DanielB `tcpdump` just shows that there is checksum error when routing packet from `srv_pub` to `srv_target`, without indication of reason, no more. Could you please be more specific, how to debug the problem using `tcpdump` ?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov, no, 499 code is not the answer of `srv.example.com`. I don't see any request in its access.log

Comment: About `tcpdump`: that's really good idea; but check the actual contents of the traffic (e.g. actual requests and responses), not just the metadata. Either caputre with `tcpdump -s0 -w file` and analyze the `file` in Wireshark or show on screen with `tcpdump -s0 -A`; read manual for details.

Comment: Checksum error on outgoing traffic are not necessarily a problem if checksums are offloaded. // Remember to check on *srv_target*, too, whether traffic arrives.